# ImportError: No module named pygame windows 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to install pygame for windows and I have tried installing it using .msi file but still I get this error . My computer has Windows 8 (64-bit Operating System, x-64 based processor). My python version is 2.7.11(32 bit).

Comment: Do you have another Python version installed and installed Pygame with that? Look in your python27 directory and then go to Lib/site-packages and see if Pygame is there (most likely not).

Comment: Yes @MatthiasSchreiber there was another python version installed and pygame was installed in the other version. Thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the might be the possible error.

First, make sure that your python version and the pygame version which you are trying to download both are in same version.For your case , your python version in 2.7 , therefore you need to download pygame for version 2.7 and **NOT** for version 3.3.If you still dont get the solution, get back to me i will try to help you.

[Here](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) is the download link for pygame downloads.